# Suggestions on how to create Test Automation For Kotlin Application that was created using Jetpack Compose

Tags: automation, android-jetpack-compose, appium, robotframework

I want to create end to end automated tests for an mobile app that was created using Kotlin Jetpack compose.

I normally use Robot Framework with Appium The problem is identifying and interacting with the dynamic objects that are created at run time with Jetpack Compose. The objects change every time the application runs.

I do not want to create unit tests or change any of the app code. It needs to be an in depended test that runs on the gui of the app.

Thanks